# Is it possible to see who is connected to the guest network on a TP-Link WR840N?

Tags: wifi, router

I have a TP-Link WR840N v2 router with a guest network enabled. I'd like to view the clients connected to it, but can't figure out how to do so. I'd also like to apply MAC filtering rules for that guest network if that's possible.

Comment: I think you need to read the manual for this question.

Answer (score 1):

For clients, go to DHCP and DHCP Client List.

And for MAC filtering, you have "*how to*" from tp-link - official website:

[How to configure Wireless MAC address filter on wireless router?](http://www.tp-link.com/ph/faq-324.html)